# Ajustar una imagen de fondo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un problema quiero ajustar la imagen de fondo para que abarque toda la interfaz,pero le muevo el tamaño y aveces si me la muestra y otras veces no,me podrían ayudar en este detalle por favor gracias

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk    
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Canvas
from tkinter import NW
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sys import argv
import tkinter as tk



ventana = tk.Tk ()

ventana.geometry("900x900+0+0")
fondo=PhotoImage(file="fondo.gif")
lblFondo=Label(ventana,image=fondo).place(x=150,y=150) #fondo 

 ###############################################################################################################


img_frame = tk.Frame(ventana, height=600, width=800, bg='#faf0e6')
img_frame.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=600, width=800, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)



imagenL = None
def abrir():
    global imagenL
    ventana.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Imágenes")
    ruta=ventana.filename
    imagen = Image.open(ruta)
    imagenL = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=imagenL) 



class Ayuda_Dialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        text = ("\n")


class Main_Window:
    def __init__(self,  ventana):
        mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda",command=self.ayuda)

    def ayuda(self):
        Ayuda_Dialog(ventana)


barraMenu=Menu(ventana)
mnuArchivo=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuDiagnostico=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuAyuda=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Abrir",command = abrir)
mnuArchivo.add_separator()
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Salir",command=ventana.destroy)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=mnuArchivo)

ventana.config(menu=barraMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":            
    Main_Window(ventana)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Airam. No me queda muy clara la pregunta y el código es algo confuso. La imagen de fondo la cargas en un label pero la posiciones en (150, 150) cosa que no entiendo si quieres que abarque toda la ventana. Por otro lado el menú abrir carga una imagen que no queda muy claro dónde debe mostrarse (el canvas no lo posicionas en ningún lado). ¿A qué te refieres con  "le muevo el tamaño y aveces si me la muestra y otras veces no"?El fondo debe mostrarse siempre en posición (150,150) pero ten en cuenta que si maximizas o redimensionas la ventana esta no va a ajustar su tamaño.

Comment: [Aquí hay mucha información](https://www.google.com.do/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1JZAP_esDO703DO703&ei=VKXDWpnlB-uxgge6hpbgCg&q=Fit+a+background+image+in+python+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=Fit+a+background+image+in+python+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...232096.232096.0.233112.1.1.0.0.0.0.91.91.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.jIi3fJiQgT0) al respecto que puedes usar para resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola ,bueno de echo solo quiero poner la imagen como fondo de la interfaz el canvas es para mostrar otra imagen en pocas palabras ,a imagen de fondo es para darle presentación a la interfaz  ,pero no se si al colocar el tamaño de 150x150 sea lo correcto ya que no me muestra la imagen en toda la interfaz sino solo en una parte pequeña ,muchas gracias por tus sugerencias .

Answer (score 2):

> Traducción de la [respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24074612/8933039) por [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin)

Esta es una aplicación de ejemplo que usa Pillow para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen en la etiqueta a medida que la etiqueta cambia de tamaño:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(background="black")



class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)



        self.image = Image.open("./resource/Background.gif")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)



e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


root.mainloop()
```

Así es como funciona usando la imagen de [Lenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) como ejemplo:

[image: imagen]

> [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181434/8933039) hay otra información útil, Saludos!